# How can the uncertainty principle be used to deduce range of a force from properties of the force carrier?

Tags: particle-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, carrier-particles

**Question:**

> How can the uncertainty principle be used to deduce range of a force from properties of the force carrier?

My thoughts?

Not too sure how this can be done and would like some advice. My understanding of the uncertainty principle is that a particles position and velocity cannot be precisely determined at a given time. I'm not sure how this relates though.

Any help?

Comment: Are you talking about quantum field theory?

Comment: Yes. But I'm quite new to the topic so please keep it fairly elementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Delta E \Delta t \sim \hbar$$

This is a version of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. Instead of using momentum and position,however,the above form uses energy and time ($\Delta$ means change in).

> How can the uncertainty principle be used to deduce range of a force
>   from properties of the force carrier?

Let's take the simplest example: the force particle of electric force -- the photon.

> The uncertainty relation, $\Delta E \Delta t \sim \hbar$, tells us
>   that if we only observe a system for a time interval $\Delta$$t$,
>   there is no way that we can know the energy of the system better than
>   to within an uncertainty $\Delta E$.  So the photon can have energy
>   $\Delta E$ for a time interval $\Delta t \sim \hbar /\Delta E$,
>   without anybody being able to know if energy conservation is violated.
>   As long as the photon is reabsorbed quickly enough, there is no
>   measurable violation of energy conservation.  Since the photon must be
>   reabsorbed and cannot be detected, it is called a virtual photon.  A
>   QFT calculation of the effect of this virtual photon exchange gives
>   rise to the usual Coulomb force.  Like charges repel and unlike
>   charges attract.  virtual photon can exist for a time Δt ~ ћ/ΔE. 
>   Since for a photon the wavelength can be arbitrarily large and
>   therefore the energy arbitrarily small, we can have ΔE --> 0,  Δt -->
>   infinity.  The virtual photon can have an infinite range.

We can do this same thing, with slighty different methods, to all force carriers.

[Good reading on the topic](http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/phys250/modules/module%206/standard_model.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In quantum field theory we describe the interaction between two particles, $A$ and $B$, as being due to the exchange of a gauge boson - call this $X$. So $A$ emits a gauge boson $X$ of mass $m_X$ that travels over to particle $B$ and is absorbed. If the lifetime of the gauge boson is $t_X$ then the range will be of order $ct_X$:

$$ d \approx ct_X \tag{1} $$

The lifetime $t_X$ can be obtained from the energy-time uncertainty principle:

$$ \Delta t \Delta E \approx \frac{\hbar}{2} \tag{2} $$

The argument is that in this case $\Delta t$ is the lifetime of the gauge boson and $\Delta E$ is the rest mass of the gauge boson, that is:

$$ \Delta E = m_X c^2 $$

If we substitute this into equation (2) and rearrange we get:

$$ t_X \approx \frac{\hbar}{2m_Xc^2} $$

And substituting this into equation (1) gives the range of the force $d$ as:

$$ ct_X \approx \frac{\hbar}{2m_Xc} $$

So the range is inversely proportional to the mass of the $X$ boson.

But note that this is an exceedingly rough and ready calculation and at best can give only an order of magnitude approximation. The particle exchange actually produces a [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential):

$$ V(r) = -g^2 \frac{e^{-m_Xr}}{r} $$

where $g$ is a constant called the [coupling constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant). Actually the coupling constant isn't really constant, but depends on energy. This is why the strength of the fundamental forces changes with energy.